# ggsurvplot cuting off curve on last day

Tags: r, plot, survival-analysis

I have produced the following survival curves (Kaplan-Meier analysis) plot with ggsurvplot in package survminer:

```
kpplot<-ggsurvplot(fit = fit, xlab = "Time to failure (days)", ylab = "Survival Probability", 
           risk.table = T, risk.table.y.text = F, censor = T, linetype = "strata", ggtheme = theme_bw(), 
           palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),data=q4,conf.int = T)

kpplot$plot+scale_x_continuous(breaks=c(0,7,14,21,28,35,42,49))
```

[image: survplot]

The plot is cutting of at day 42, I am unsure how to solve this? I have tried adding a breakpoint beyond day 42, but it does not work, and it also removes the risk table. Any suggestions?

EDIT:

- use coord_cartesian
- still removes risk table but solve cut-off issue

```
kpplot<-ggsurvplot(fit = fit, xlab = "Time to failure (days)", ylab = "Survival Probability", 
           risk.table = T, risk.table.y.text = F, censor = T, linetype = "strata", ggtheme = theme_bw(), 
           palette = c("#E7B800", "#2E9FDF"),data=q4,conf.int = T,coord_cartesian(x=c(0,50)))

kpplot<-kpplot$plot+coord_cartesian(x=c(0,42))
```

[image]

Comment: When does your last failure occur?  I'm guessing it's at Day 42.  The KM estimate of survival is not valid beyound the time of the last failure.

Comment: If you *need* to extend the axis beyond the last data point, try `coord_cartesian()` rather than `scale_x_continuous()`.

Comment: Sorry, it does work, but it still removes the risk table. Any idea how I would change this and keep the risk table?